# Evaluate the double integrals and draw the regions of d

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

> $$\int\int_D(1+xy)\mathrm dx\;\mathrm dy$$ where $D$ is the region given by $y\geq 0$ and $1\leq x^2+y^2\leq 2$.

I have been told to evaluate this integral but I am struggling to do so. I have changed the inequality for $1<(x^2)+(y^2)<2$ so it shows the limits for $x$ but the limits for $y$ tend to $0$ and an unknown value which confuses me. What would be the right way to answer this question?

Comment: the question is double integrate (1+xy)dxdy given that y>and=0 and 1<=(x^2+y^2)<=2. the question didn't import when I did this

Comment: Did you try to draw the $D$ region? Also, are you allowed to change to polar coordinates?

Comment: I couldn't get the graph out, I think I went wrong somewhere with the diagram and I am allowed to change it to polar coordinates

Comment: I just don't know how to answer it

Comment: I’ve edited the tags; complex integration is for complex variables, not difficult integrals.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use polar coordinates... The integration region is given by
$$
D = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y \ge 0 \wedge 1 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq 2\}
$$

or, in polar coordinates, by

$$
D^* = \{(\rho, \theta): 1 \leq \rho \leq 2 \wedge 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi\}
$$

now you have that
$$
\iint_D (1+xy) dx dy = \iint_{D^*} \rho (1+(\rho \cos \theta)(\rho \sin \theta))d \rho d\theta = \int_0^{\pi} \int_1^2\rho(1+\frac 12 \rho^2 \sin(2 \theta))d\rho d\theta = \cdots = \frac{3 \pi}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: this integral is equal to $$
\int_0^{\pi} \, \int_1^2 \,(1+r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta)r \mathrm dr \mathrm d\theta
$$

Comment: What happened toe the $1$ in $(1+xy)$? And how did you account for $y>0$?

Comment: @Andrei my mistake. Should be fixed

Answer (score 1):

The domain $D$ is the area between disks of radius $1$ and $2$, above the $y=0$ (the horizontal axis). In addition to the solutions in the polar coordinates, you can observe that the integral of the $xy$ term is zero (for every positive $y$ you integrate symmetrically around $0$). Then $$\iint_D(1+xy)dxdy=\iint_D dxdy$$
This is just the area of $D$: $$\frac 12 (\pi 2^2-\pi 1^2)=\frac 32\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\iint_D(1+xy)dxdy$$
First lets think about what the region $D$ represents. since $y\ge0$ and $1\le x^2+y^2\le2$ we know that we are only looking at the top two quadrants. we also know that the formula $x^2+y^2=r^2$ represents a circle of radius, $r$. Since we have a lower limit of $1$ rather than $0$, we have a half-donut shape as our region. To evaulate this integral it is easiest to express in polar coordinates, which have the following conditions:
$$dxdy=rdrd\theta$$
$$x=r\cos\theta$$
$$y=r\sin\theta$$
$$x^2+y^2=r^2$$
so we know that our integral will be of the form:
$$I=\iint_\Omega\left(1+r^2\sin\theta\cos\theta\right)rdrd\theta$$
To determine the upper and lower bounds we must think about the polar angle, $\theta$ that we will cover. Since it is defined as going from the $+x$ $+y$ quadrant round anticlockwise, and we only want the positive region, we can see that this must be $0\le\theta\le\pi$. The limits for $r$ are easy since we already have them in the right form so we can say that $1\le r\le2$ . If we now substitute these in we obtain:
$$I=\int_0^\pi\int_1^2\left[r+r^3\sin\theta\cos\theta \right]drd\theta$$
$$I=\int_0^\pi\left[\frac{r^2}{2}+\frac{r^4}{4}\sin\theta\cos\theta\right]_{r=1}^2d\theta=\int_0^\pi\left[\frac32+\frac{15}4\sin\theta\cos\theta\right]d\theta=\int_0^\pi\left[\frac32+\frac{15}8\sin2\theta\right]d\theta=\left[\frac32\theta-\frac{15}{16}\cos2\theta\right]_{\theta=0}^\pi=\frac32\pi$$
And this is your final answer. Normally for any circular region defined in this way polar coordinates are the easiest way to proceed.